# Iterating over list of arrays in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, associative-array

I need to iterate over couple of key-value arrays (associative arrays) in bash. Here's my last attempt:

```
declare -A ARR1
ARR1[foo]=bar

declare -A ARR2
ARR2[foo]=baz

arrays=(ARR1 ARR2)

for idx in "${arrays[@]}"; do
    echo ${${idx}[foo]};
done
```

which is wrong of course (syntax error), but at this moment, I have no other ideas how to deal with it. Whereas in the following example there are no errors, but the output is just a name of an array.

```
for idx in "${array[@]}"; do
    echo "${idx[foo]}";
done

------- OUTPUT -------
ARR1
ARR2
```

### EDIT

Ok, I was able to do it by using `eval`:

```
eval echo \${${idx}[foo]};
```

However, I read that using `eval` in bash scripts is not such a good idea. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash 4.3-alpha introduced the [*nameref* attribute](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters), which could be used in this case:

```
declare -A arr1=([foo]=bar)
declare -A arr2=([foo]=baz)
arrays=(arr1 arr2)

for idx in "${arrays[@]}"; do
    declare -n temp="$idx"
    echo "${temp[foo]}"
done
```

gives the output

```
bar
baz
```

As pointed out by [kojiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418413/kojiro) in his comment, storing the array names in an array to iterate over is not actually required as long as the names have a shared prefix.

```
arrays=(arr1 arr2)

for idx in "${arrays[@]}"; do
```

could be replaced by

```
for idx in "${!arr@}"; do
```

Notice that despite the exclamation mark, this has nothing to do with indirect expansion.

---

#### Relevant excerpts from the reference manual

Section "[Shell Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters)":

> A variable can be assigned the *nameref* attribute using the `-n`
>   option to the `declare` or `local` builtin commands (see [Bash
>   Builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Builtins))
>   to create a *nameref*, or a reference to another variable. This allows
>   variables to be manipulated indirectly. Whenever the nameref variable
>   is referenced or assigned to, the operation is actually performed on
>   the variable specified by the nameref variable's value. A nameref is
>   commonly used within shell functions to refer to a variable whose name
>   is passed as an argument to the function. For instance, if a variable
>   name is passed to a shell function as its first argument, running
>
> ```
> declare -n ref=$1
> ```
>
> inside the function creates a nameref variable `ref` whose value is
>   the variable name passed as the first argument. References and
>   assignments to `ref` are treated as references and assignments to the
>   variable whose name was passed as `$1`.
>
> If the control variable in a `for` loop has the nameref attribute, the
>   list of words can be a list of shell variables, and a name reference
>   will be established for each word in the list, in turn, when the loop
>   is executed. Array variables cannot be given the `-n` attribute.
>   However, nameref variables can reference array variables and
>   subscripted array variables. Namerefs can be unset using the `-n`
>   option to the `unset` builtin (see [Bourne Shell
>   Builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins)).
>   Otherwise, if `unset` is executed with the name of a nameref variable
>   as an argument, the variable referenced by the nameref variable will
>   be unset.

Section "[Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)":

> ```
> ${!prefix*}
> ${!prefix@}
> ```
>
> Expands to the names of variables whose names begin with *`prefix`*,
>   separated by the first character of the `IFS` special variable. When
>   `@` is used and the expansion appears within double quotes, each
>   variable name expands to a separate word.

Comment: It's not necessary to keep the names of the arrays in another array – as long as they have a unique name _pattern_ you can reference them that way. In this case, something like `${!arr*}`

Comment: Isn't it the same option as @ffledgling provided but in the form of bash builtin?

Comment: @kashpersky They're similar, but not the same. The above mentioned http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006 talks about some of it. Namerefs are proper references and can be used, for example, to more easily deal with arrays as positional parameters in functions.

Comment: Thank you @kojiro. ${!arr@} does the job:)

Comment: Namerefs are actually mentioned in that blog post, briefly.

Comment: @BenjaminW. ok, thanks. Then this answer should be accepted. I hope that ffledgling doesn't get offended:)

Comment: @kojiro, I've never seen that before. Where is it documented?

Comment: @glennjackman In the bash manual under Parameter Expansion, between Substring Expansion and Array Expansion.

Comment: Nice. I've never seen it in action before. All of a sudden, the questions asking about handling $VAR1, $VAR2, $VAR3, etc, don't seem to call out so blatantly for an array answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this like with indirect substitution, but ideally you don't want to use bash for something like this if it's anything but a one-off script.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex

declare -A ARR1
ARR1[foo]=bar

declare -A ARR2
ARR2[foo]=baz

arrays=(ARR1 ARR2)

for idx in "${arrays[@]}"; do
  x="${idx}[foo]" # Store as a string in a variable
  echo ${!x} # Reference using indirection.
done
```

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006 for more info.